# Pandas Dataframe set column value based on row count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called 'segments' that looks like this:

```
               COL_A
0              10135
1              10135
2              10135
3              10140
4              10140
```

And I want to get it to look like this. Where Outdegree is the number of rows that contain the value in COL_A, so for example 10135 is in 3 rows, so OUTDEGREE is set to 3 for each row:

```
               COL_A    OUTDEGREE
0              10135    3
1              10135    3
2              10135    3
3              10140    2
4              10140    2
```

Here is what I'm trying but isn't working:

```
segments['OUTDEGREE'] = len(segments[segments['COL_A'] == segments['COL_A']])
```

That code adds up ALL the rows and gives the grand total to the OUTDEGREE column

Comment: `df['New']=df.groupby('COL_A')['COL_A'].transform('count')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either `len` or `'count'` with transform function to achieve that

```
df['OUTDEGREE'] = df.groupby('COL_A')['COL_A'].transform(len)
df
```

or

```
df['OUTDEGREE'] = df.groupby('COL_A')['COL_A'].transform('count')
```

Out:

```
    COL_A   OUTDEGREE
0   10135   3
1   10135   3
2   10135   3
3   10140   2
4   10140   2
```